# Can't get Jquery to work correctly outside of JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle, document-ready

I have a basic table that I am creating from text input and when you click the "addTask" button it adds a tr with an empty text box and clicking the "delTask" button should delete the rows from the table that have checkboxes checked.

Everything works perfectly in JSFiddle (except the line to render last textbox readonly which only works outside of JSFiddle) but when I try to test the code out live the "delTask" button does not work correctly. It will delete all rows except the first one in the table.

I'm fairly new to JQuery so please don't judge if it's something simple but I have really searched for an answer and tried everything I could find. Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong here? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** I have fixed the initial issue of the delTask button not working at all by changing $(":checkbox[checked='true']") to $(".checkbox:checked") when testing outside of JSFiddle but still cant get the button to delete the first row on the table in a live test. 
JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/2aLfr794/14/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<table id="tasks" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="text"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
<input type="button" id="addTask" value="Add Task" />
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
<input type="button" id="delTask" value="Delete Tasks" />


<script>

$("#addTask").click(function(){
    var newTxt = $('<tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td><input type="text" class="text"></td></tr>');
    $(".text").last().prop("readonly", true);

    $("#tasks").append(newTxt);
});

    $("#delTask").click(function(){
            $(".checkbox:checked").each(function(){
                var curTask = $(this).parents('tr');
                curTask.remove();
            });
    });


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try with `$(".checkbox:checked")` instead of `$(".checkbox[checked='true']")`. Provide link to fiddle

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: @Satpal   You're solution worked!! It's working perfectly now. Thanks a million!

Comment: New problem, I can delete all but the first task outside of JSFiddle. I will add a link to the JSFiddle in the description above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Issues:

1.You are not assigning class `checkbox` to default `checkbox` and dynamically created `checkboxes`.

2.To access a checked element the syntax is  `$(".checkbox[checked='checked']")`

Your Updated Code:

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body>
    <table id="tasks" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type="button" id="addTask" value="Add Task" class="addSubmit" />&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type="button" id="delTask" value="Delete Selected Tasks" />
    <script>
        $("#addTask").click(function() {
            var newTxt = $('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td><td><input type="text" class="text"></td></tr>');
            $(".text").last().prop("readonly", true);
            $("#tasks").append(newTxt);
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#delTask").click(function() {
                console.log($(".checkbox[checked='checked']"))
                $(".checkbox:checked").each(function() {
                    var curTask = $(this).parents('tr');
                    curTask.remove();

                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: This answer solved all issues I was having. I had tried assigning a class to checkboxes but didn't have the console.log added in. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if you get "$ is not defined" error, try writing 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` as `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Note the "http:" before "//cdnjs" which is needed when you are running those from local machine, and not a webserver. At least it was always required for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked")
```

worked for me